# How to add a save button in TinyMCE (jQuery custom theme)

Tags: jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg

This is the example on TinyMCE's website concerning the jQuery custom theme:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/K9baab

I've been trying to figure out for hours on how to add a button to save the content (=post the form). I don't want to add a submit button to the form but a button in the menu bar of TinyMCE.

How is this done?

I've tried the most logical thing by adding the following line:

```
'<input type="checkbox" id="save" data-mce-command="save" /><label for="save">Save</label>' +
```

This adds a button but the form isn't posted when I click it.

Please advice.

Regards,

Roel

Comment: Tiny MCE is a javascript-driven visual editor, not an html *form*.  You'd have to capture the click event of that button using javascript, and then trigger the save on the containing form.

Comment: But TinyMCE offers a lot of plugins, "Save" being one of them. How do I implement this into this kind of implementation in TinyMCE? I've tried using the plugins property and setting it to "save", but no succes.

Comment: you need to add the button too usong the button config

Comment: How do I do this?
I've tried adding the line you see in the topicstart, this shows me a button on the toolbar, but how do I make it post my form?